# Phonegap app with server links couldn't load Childbrowser plugin

Tags: html, cordova, anchor, childbrowser

I have an app build upon PhoneGap. The app contains only one index.html file that contains PhoneGap dependant js and plug-in files files and its working fine.
In the index.html file, am using window.location to load an url from server. I want to call childbrowser plug-in from the server html file included in the app using window.location. That means the html file loaded from server has anchor links that would be loaded in child browser. I have tried by including childbrowser plug-in in to the app and called the event from server js, but it is not working. Any idea. Please help

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you set `window.location` to a URL on your server and leave `index.html`, PhoneGap is no longer loaded, so you can't use ChildBrowser.

Instead of setting `window.location`, you need to use `childBrowser.showWebPage()` in `index.html`:

```js
window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage( 'example.com/your-page-on-server' );
```